# Авторизация в steam

Tags: php, rsa

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на [сайте](https://steamcommunity.com/login/home) стима
Как происходит авторизация можно посмотреть [здесь](https://steamstore-a.akamaihd.net/public/shared/javascript/login.js?v=ceOWNLnkyZcP&l=russian) (CLoginPromptManager.prototype.OnRSAKeyResponse)

Для шифрования ключа использую библиотеку phplibsec. Пароль шифрую следующим образом:

```
public function encryptPassword($password, $publickey_exp, $publickey_mod)
{
    $RSA = new RSA();
    $RSA->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);

    $key = [
        'modulus'        => new BigInteger($publickey_mod, 16),
        'publicExponent' => new BigInteger($publickey_exp, 16)
    ];

    $RSA->loadKey($key, RSA::PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW);
    return urlencode(base64_encode($RSA->encrypt($password)));
}
```

Все работало до определенного момента, потом начало выдавать ошибки:

```
Notice (1024): Message representative out of range [ROOT/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php, line 2225]

Fatal error: Call to a member function toBytes() on boolean in /var/www/cakephp/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php on line 2062
```

либо

```
Notice (1024): Integer too large [ROOT/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php, line 2064]
```

var_dump:

```
public_exp: 010001
public_mod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
```

Помогите исправить проблему.

**update:**

Репозиторий проекта: github.com/SpekToR-ru/Awesomenauts-Match-Players

Пробовал сделать шифрование пароля через js (как на сайте стима), но пока не взлетело - ответ стима: Incorrect login.

PS. Присоединяйтесь кому интересна эта тема)

Answer (score 1):

Есть подозрение, что второй параметр метода `encrypt` все-таки должен быть целочисленным. Ну или отсутствовать, если вас устраивает дефолтное значение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, пробовал убирать, но разницы нет. Мне кажется тут дело в модуле и экспоненте, которые присылает стим. Также периодически возникает ошибка "Integer too large" (добавил в описание). До этого все работало и я ничего не обновлял. Потом перестало. Может что-то изменили.

Залил на github [репозиторий](https://github.com/SpekToR-ru/Awesomenauts-Match-Players). 
Файлы ProfilesController.php (метод authorize) и Profile.php (метод encryptPassword)

Comment: Также пытался сделать шифрование через JS (подгружал методы со стима), но, к сожалению, что-то не прокатило (Incorrect login), буду пытаться еще. Это более реалистичный вариант для меня пока что)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, оказалась в версии PHP.. После установки (для теста) версии 7, все нормально заработало. До этого php была также 64bit'ной (проверил перед удалением). Может проблема была в одном из модулей. На досуге поэксперементирую.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас правильный вариант такой:

```
function encryptPassword($password, $publickey_exp, $publickey_mod)
{
    $RSA = new Crypt_RSA();
    $RSA->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);

    $key = [
        'modulus'        => new Math_BigInteger($publickey_mod, 16),
        'publicExponent' => new Math_BigInteger($publickey_exp, 16)
    ];

    $RSA->loadKey($key, CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW);
    $RSA->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
    return base64_encode($RSA->encrypt($password));
}
```